# OpenAI retry count override

Tags: python, callback, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api

I am using SQLite dB answer retrieval using Lang chain model and ChatGPT. if the billing limit reached, chat gpt show a message,
*"Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details."*
retry count is 5 by default, is there a way to override this limit. because it takes almost 30-40 seconds to complete the retry. It only throws exception after the completion of retry. [You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.], so it is not possible catch by exception. Is there a way to fix this by overriding the error class/by using a retry count flag/by using a callback(stdout)?

I tried to use the inbuilt debug function to find out the source of the error, but could not find the source of the error.

Comment: llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name=model, request_timeout=120), increasing the timeout would help

Comment: I tried it, it does not work.

Comment: it would be difficult as the logic is on OpenAI API side :(

Comment: Are you sure the default of max_retries is 5?
I can see the follwoing in langchain\chat_models\openai.py:

    max_retries: int = 6
    """Maximum number of retries to make when generating."""

Answer (score 2):

In the `ChatOpenAI` class constructor you have the option to customize the `max_retries` value by overriding it.

```py
chat_instance = ChatOpenAI(max_retries=5)
```

> I'm using Python library version `0.28.1`.